# Having multiples Jobs, how to submit then as a one unique job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jobs

I have some jobs runned with an script.sh like this:

```
JobA
JobB
```

Each job is runned via script, and the cluster 'see' each job.

So my intention is to package all jobs in one big job so that the cluster process all like one unique job.

I've been using the library Spark Launcher like this

```
class jobLaunch{
 val spark = new SparkLauncher()

      .setAppResource("../lib/assembly-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar") // TODO
      .setMainClass("com.main.class")
      .setMaster("yarn")
      .setConf("spark.ui.port","1234")
      .launch()

def startExternalProcess = {
  val processOut = spark.getInputStream
  var is_finished = false

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    def run() {
      val exit = spark.exitValue()
      is_finished = true
    }
  }).start()

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    def run() {
      while (!is_finished) {
        scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(processOut).getLines.foreach{info(_)}
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      }
    }
  }).start()
  info("hello there")
  val exit = spark.exitValue()
}
```

...

```
override def run(sc: SparkContext, hivec: HiveContext): Unit = {
   val jl = new jobLaunch
   val jl2 = new jobLaunch
   jl.startExternalProcess
   jl2.startExternalProcess

 }
}
```

This code is for testing purposes, when I was running I realized that the jobs where running like a proccess, without using the cluster.

So I still don't know if I can run sub-jobs inside one job.

Comment: The job is defined inside a sparkContext, so to do that both jobs should share the same sc

Comment: Gracias, @rhernando. Can you please explain what is a 'sc'?